# Tool for quickly testing Android layouts

Tags: android, layout, android-emulator, intellij-idea

Android layouts are very tricky to get right. Especially for an inexperienced layouter like me. At the moment I use the following workflow:

- Design the layout in IntelliJ, using IntelliJ's GUI preview window
- Test the layout on my device
- Test the layout on different emulator images

This approach has several problems:

- The IntelliJ is very inaccurate (often the layout looks very different on the device)
- Testing on my device is good, but here I have only one fixed resolution and PPI
- The emulator takes AGES to start up. If using multiple emulators things get worse

That's why I'm looking for an alternate solution: a tool, that quickly renders Android layouts (no app logic required). This tool should support different resolution and PPI settings and should be as close to the actual looks on real devices as possible.

Is there such a tool?
What other alternatives are there?

Comment: I find Eclipse to be a pretty passable layout renderer, but running Eclipse just for the layouts seems like overkill.

Comment: I too use eclipse as I use it for all of the development work. but i found this website pretty cool for making good UI components and directly pasting them. have a look http://android-holo-colors.com/

Comment: Don't really know any good tools but Eclipse. Basically the best and fastest way anyway is to get a nice range of real devices to test on.